# I have a question for my project by opensource

Tags: python, pyinstaller, specifications

I downloaded the project from https://github.com/ju1ce/Mediapipe-VR-Fullbody-Tracking and tried to create an executable (exe) file using PyInstaller without making any modifications to the 'mediapipepose.py' file. However, I encountered an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin\mediapipepose.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'CameraStream' from 'helpers' (C:\Users\국현우\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI92002\helpers_init_.pyc)
```

Here is the original spec file in the open-source project folder:'

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['mediapipepose.py'],
         pathex=['bin/'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/site-          packages/mediapipe/modules','mediapipe/modules'),],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='mediapipepose',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='mediapipepose')'
```

And here is the spec file from my local directory after downloading the open-source project:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-





block_cipher = None






 a = Analysis(
 ['C:\\logy\\Mediapipe-VR-Fullbody-Tracking\\bin\\mediapipepose.py'],
 pathex=[],
 binaries=[],
 datas=[],
 hiddenimports=[],  
 hookspath=[],
 hooksconfig={},
 runtime_hooks=[],
 excludes=[],
 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
 win_private_assemblies=False,
 cipher=block_cipher,
 noarchive=False,
 )
 pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
a.scripts,
a.binaries,
a.zipfiles,
a.datas,
[],
name='mediapipepose',
debug=False,
bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
strip=False,
upx=True,
upx_exclude=[],
runtime_tmpdir=None,
console=False,
disable_windowed_traceback=False,
argv_emulation=False,
target_arch=None,
codesign_identity=None,
entitlements_file=None,
)
```

What could be causing the issue?'

I was trying to create an executable (exe) file using PyInstaller for the downloaded open-source 'py' file, and the error code is the result of the creation process.

```
bin\mediapipepose.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'CameraStream' from 'helpers' (C:\Users\국현우\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI92002\helpers_init_.pyc
```

this is execute result

Comment: You can write the (minimized) version of your question in the title, instead of defining the title as "I have a question", which we obviously know, because you would not be here otherwise.

Comment: Have you verified you can execute the program by running `python mediapipepose.py` (or whatever file has the `main` function)?